# Hessian matrix from IRLS

Tags: generalized-linear-model, least-squares, iteration-methods

I am following computation statistics by givens and after looking at the supplementary code, I find that:

$$I''(\beta) = -Z^TWZ$$
Where Z are the column vectors of the covariates, and W is the diagonal matrix with ith diagonal entry $\pi_i(1-\pi_i)$

The code is provided as the following:

```
hessian = matrix(0,2,2)
hessian[1,1] = -sum(w)
hessian[1,2] = hessian[2,1] = -t(w)%*%z[,2]
hessian[2,2] = -t(w)%*%(z[,2]^2)
```

Reference to authors text for code: [computational statistics](https://www.stat.colostate.edu/computationalstatistics/).
I cannot understand where the author gets the values for `hessian[1, 2]` and `hessian[2,2]`

Comment: Evidently the first covariate is the intercept term where the column of $Z$ is all ones.

Comment: @whuber Sure, I have got the part already understood. However, I was interested in knowing how the author decided on the equations for the hessian. I had assumed that `hessian[1,1]` and `hessian[2,2]` were going to be equal. I do not understand why `hessian[2,2]` the Z is squared.

Comment: I think perhaps you haven't understood that, because it explains everything.  In effect, `z[, 1]` disappears because it always equals $1.$  The rest follows from the rules of matrix multiplication.  I'm making some guesses here because the appearance of `t(w)` for an allegedly diagonal matrix is strange due to the superfluous call to `t`.  I am supposing `w` is a an $n\times 1$ column matrix of the diagonal entries, not a square diagonal matrix.