# R: Parameterization differences betwen MASS::glm.nb and glmmTMB "nbinom2"

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmmtmb

I'd like opinions on two differing GLM outputs in RStudio.

I model count data (dung pellets) over 21 sites, using quadrats counted as an area offset. I started with a GLM Poisson regression for the definition of the model structure, which was strongly overdispersed & zero inflated. I moved to Negative Binomial, which fixed both issues, but I have differing results according to the package used (MASS:glm.nb and glmmTMB nbinom2). They give the same theta estimation, same AIC, but different SE & z-values, in particular for one predictor, which appears as significant in one but not the other package. This is prior to model selection.

Thus, I'd like to know what are the differences in parameterization between the two packages used? From what I've read, they seem to use the same variance formulas, both estimated through Maximum Likelihood:

- glmmTMB : variance = µ(1 + µ/k)
- MASS: variance = μ+μ²/θ so that θ=1/k

I am suspecting that it is related to MASS::glm.nb dropping constants from the log-likelihood calculations while glmmTMB is not, but I cannot confirm it.

I'm inclined to stick with MASS as I don't use any RE here, but I'd like to know what is happening.

code output:

```
> # MASS package
> mod.nbmass <- glm.nb(pellets ~ RS1+RS2+RS4+RS5+RS6+offset(log(quadrats)), link = "log", data=data_site)
> summary(mod.nbmass)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = pellets ~ RS1 + RS2 + RS4 + RS5 + RS6 + offset(log(quadrats)), 
    data = data_site, link = "log", init.theta = 0.9808088892)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.6923  -0.9313  -0.1119   0.2173   1.5372  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  0.17109    0.22170   0.772   0.4403  
RS1         -0.04392    0.34372  -0.128   0.8983  
RS2          0.21905    0.31118   0.704   0.4815  
RS4         -0.04524    0.31740  -0.143   0.8866  
RS5          0.21135    0.34775   0.608   0.5433  
RS6         -0.67892    0.33963  -1.999   0.0456 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.9808) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 29.252  on 20  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 24.854  on 15  degrees of freedom
AIC: 246.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.981 
          Std. Err.:  0.290 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -232.429 
> # glmmTMB package
> mod.nbTMB<-glmmTMB(pellets ~ RS1+RS2+RS4+RS5+RS6+offset(log(quadrats)), family="nbinom2", data=data_site)
> summary(mod.nbTMB)
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          pellets ~ RS1 + RS2 + RS4 + RS5 + RS6 + offset(log(quadrats))
Data: data_site

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   246.4    253.7   -116.2    232.4       14 


Dispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 0.981 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.17109    0.22163   0.772    0.440
RS1         -0.04393    0.39138  -0.112    0.911
RS2          0.21905    0.26685   0.821    0.412
RS4         -0.04525    0.30701  -0.147    0.883
RS5          0.21135    0.40676   0.520    0.603
RS6         -0.67892    0.48995  -1.386    0.166
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the coefficients, AIC, log-likelihood, dispersion parameters etc. are the same (up to rounding), and only the SE/z values differ, implies that this is **not** a difference in parameterization. There are two and possibly three differences between `glm.nb` and `glmmTMB` in the way that the covariance matrices of the fixed effects (and hence the SEs/Z-statistics/etc.) are computed.

**tl;dr** the issues are fairly subtle, but I expect that where there is a difference the `glmmTMB` estimates of the SE will be either more accurate or *conservative* (the first point below would suggest that `glmmTMB` SEs are too small; the second and third would say that where there is a difference, they would be more accurate than `glm.nb`'s ...)

### ML vs REML estimates of covariance

The maximum likelihood estimate of a variance is something like $\sum (y-\bar y)^2/N$, whereas an unbiased estimate (the *Bessel correction*) divides by $n-1$ rather than $n$. In the case of a (G)LM with $p$ parameters, the denominator is typically taken as $n-p$. `glmmTMB` effectively uses `n` rather than `n-p`, so the SEs will differ by a factor of $\sqrt{n/(n-p)}$. This has come up recently, see [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/969) for more discussion/another example.

### accounting for uncertainty in the dispersion parameter

`glm.nb` computes the covariance matrix *conditional* on $\theta = \hat \theta$, whereas `glmmTMB` computes the covariance matrix that includes the uncertainty in the parameter estimates derived from the uncertainty in $\theta$ (the resulting unconditional variances can actually be *smaller* than the corresponding conditional variances, if there is a negative correlation between the estimate of the dispersion parameter and the estimated effects of the covariates).

### observed information vs. expected (Fisher) information

I'm not sure whether this applies in this case, but `glm()` and friends (including `glm.nb`) compute the covariance based on a slightly different metric, the *expected (Fisher) information*, rather than the *observed information* (or "Hessian", the second derivative matrix at the MLE: see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/635130/difference-between-glm-covariance-matrix-from-mle-vs-irls-for-non-canonical-lin)). I'm not sure whether the log link is the *canonical* link for the negative binomial distribution or not (probably not?); if it is, then this source of difference wouldn't apply here.

Here is some exploration of the issues — doesn't quite match the example in the question, but as it wasn't reproducible ...

```r
L <- load(url("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/eeid/data/gopherdat2.RData"))
library(MASS)
library(glmmTMB)
m1 <- glm.nb(shells ~ factor(year) + offset(log(Area)),
             data = Gdat)
(sd1 <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m1))))
##      (Intercept) factor(year)2005 factor(year)2006 
##       0.3004183        0.4680113        0.4268809 

m2 <- glmmTMB(shells ~ factor(year) + offset(log(Area)),
             family = nbinom2, data = Gdat)

## coefficients are equal ...
all.equal(coef(m1), fixef(m2)$cond, tolerance = 1e-7)

(sd2 <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m2)$cond)))
##     (Intercept) factor(year)2005 factor(year)2006 
##       0.2942739        0.4614845        0.4309163 

## accounting for denominator doesn't entirely resolve the issue
n <- nobs(m2)
npar <- length(fixef(m2)$cond)
(sd2*sqrt(n/(n-npar)))
##  (Intercept) factor(year)2005 factor(year)2006 
##    0.3101919        0.4864474        0.4542256 

## derive conditional covariance matrix (i.e., ignoring effects of theta)
## combine with denominator effect (still doesn't entirely resolve the difference)
ss <- TMB::sdreport(m2$obj)
newsd <- sqrt(diag(solve(solve(ss$cov.fixed)[1:3,1:3])))
(newsd*sqrt(n/(n-npar)))
##      beta      beta      beta 
## 0.3072275 0.4853313 0.4482258
```

Using `bbmle` gives nearly identical results to `glmmTMB` (not surprising as the methods used — ML estimate of variance, unconditional covariances, observed information/Hessian — are the same ...)

```r
library(bbmle)
m3 <- mle2(shells ~ dnbinom(mu = exp(logmu)*Area, size = exp(logsize)),
           parameters = list(logmu ~ factor(year)),
           start = list(logmu = 1, logsize = 1),
           data = Gdat)
all.equal(unname(coef(m3)[1:3]), unname(fixef(m2)$cond), tolerance = 1e-5)
sqrt(diag(vcov(m3)))
##      logmu.(Intercept) logmu.factor(year)2005 logmu.factor(year)2006 
##              0.2942785              0.4614903              0.4309221 
##                logsize 
##             0.6909350
```